# How to fix CVE-2021-28170 Vulnerability in org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1; cannot find newer library version

Tags: java, jstl, dependency-management

The referenced CVE says "...Jakarta Expression Language implementation before 3.0.4..." Implying that a version 3.0.4 is available.

I'm darned if I can find it!

Mavenrepo (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl) and maven central (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/versions) only have up to 3.0.1 (the version I am using).

Has anybody tackled this? Any guidance gratefully accepted.

Comment: It's talking about [this project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.el). Not the one you are looking at.

Comment: So the question is how to find the fixed version, not how to fix the issue.

Comment: @aled, yes...how to find the latest version of the library that does not suffer the CVE

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, the page you linked is just to the project/specs, not to usable implementations?

Comment: This makes no sense. You're confusing JSTL with EL. They're not the same. JSTL are these `<c:xxx>` tags. EL are these `${...}` expressions. See abovelinked duplicate to learn what exactly EL is. We're currently already at EL 5.0. Tomcat 10.1.x is using EL 5.x not 3.x.

Comment: @Balusc, indeed el is not the same as jstl. The CVE (forgot to give the URL: https://devhub.checkmarx.com/cve-details/CVE-2021-28170/)  is posted against a group of libraries. I already use "jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:5.0.1" but I interpret my dependency report as telling me to "get a newer version of  the component that you have not yet updated," namely: "org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1".

Comment: MUCH digging around (taking a look at what is packaged with in the Glassfish 8.0.0-M3 distribution) led me to: "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.wasp/wasp" 3.2.2, which seems to meet requirements as "Eclipse compatible implementation of Jakarta Server Pages." NOWHERE did I find this repackaging documented :-(

Comment: It is also worth noting that both "org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1" and "org.glassfish.wasp:wasp:3.2.2" actually package implementations of the standard tag library.

Comment: So the "dependency report" was plain wrong. Report to the tool's vendor/maintainer. The CVE is referring to Sun EL RI as available [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.el/el-ri/3.0.4). WaSP is just the [JSP RI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/wasp). None of both have anything to do with JSTL except that JSTL in turn depends on EL and that JSTL (and EL) can be used on JSP (and Facelets).